# How to start the weblogic server using global variables

Tags: java, server, weblogic-10.x

My startup script for weblogic 10.3.3 is startWeblogic.sh which resides under mydomain. i do not want to disclose startup script path to my peers. so i would like define the global variable in sunOS and use userdefined commands like

**server start**   -> ./startWeblogic.sh this should start the server.
**server stop**    ->/stopWeblogic.sh this should stop the server.

from anywhere. so that people do not know where actually the start and stop scripts reside

Please help me out.

Comment: This is a very generic sys admin question. Have you looked at setting up a service? Look at something like http://serverfault.com/questions/69847/linux-how-to-give-a-user-permission-to-restart-apache

Answer (score -1):

You can use rc scripts but for solaris better use SMF

First create a XML containing the scripts location and its dependencies (basically we can take the example template which comes with Solaris 10 and edit a few lines since all NM requires is a mounted filesystem, network and multiuser run-level).

Create file as shown below Admin.xml and place it under /var/svc/manifest/application/management/ .

```
#! /bin/bash

case "$1" in
start)
DOMAIN_HOME = /opt/Oracle/Middleware/user_projetcs/domains/basedomain
$DOMAIN_HOME/bin/startWebLogic.sh
;;
stop)
$WL_HOME/server/bin/stopWebLogic.sh
;;
*)
echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
exit 1
esac

exit_status
```

Lets place this script under
/lib/svc/method/ so it can be imported in our service database.

Now, lets import it and activate:

## svccfg import /var/svc/manifest/application/management/Admin

## svcadm enable svc:/application/management/Admin:default

Also you can check below link

http://philtheitmonkey.blogspot.in/2011/08/starting-weblogic-managed-servers-using.html